# When can "très" modify a noun?

Tags: adverbes

The following is a sentence in a grammar textbook<sup>1</sup> :

> Il s’agit maintenant de faire **très** attention. 
> We/You should be very careful now.

It surprised me that "très" could be used to modify a noun ("attention")! I had thought that "très" could only modify an adjective or another adverb.

---

[This](https://www.thoughtco.com/synonyms-for-tres-1371419) website says that:

> "You can use très in front of adjectives, adverbs, and even certain nouns, such as those that refer to feelings but use avoir—"to be."

and it gives a single example of *très* modifying a noun:

> J'ai très **faim**. > I am very hungry.

But I note that this explanation doesn't apply to the first sentence I quoted in this question ("Il s'agit maintenant de faire très attention"); that sentence isn't referring to a feeling, and doesn't use avoir.

---

Looking at the WordReference [page](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/tr%C3%A8s) for "très", I see three expressions where "très" seems to modify a noun:

- avoir très envie de faire [qch]
- être très famille
- être très femme

But, I don't see "avoir très faim" or "faire très attention" in this list.

---

So, I'm wondering, when is "très" allowed to modify a noun? Can it actually modify *any* noun? Or does it basically modify a noun only in fixed expressions (and that I should consider "faire très attention" and "avoir très faim" as fixed expressions)?

Can you give some example sentences where "très" is used to modify a noun?

---

<sup>1. Monique L'Huiller, "Advanced French Grammar", p. 255</sup>

Comment: Wordreference does not give systematic explanations. It's just a little bit of everything. So it should not be surprising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Très*** can modify any noun as long as this noun represent something with some characteristics that allow it to be used adjectivally.

eg.

> *Si on prend une région **très Macron** - la Bretagne -, en réalité, c'est **très Macron** à Rennes et un peu moins dans les zones rurales.* [Europe 1](https://www.europe1.fr/politique/christophe-guilluy-les-metropoles-mondialisees-vont-voter-en-masse-pour-macron-3314999)

> *Je trouve que Baker fait **très chauffeur de maître**.*, Roger Borniche, *Le Gringo*, 2014.

However, the fact ***très*** can modify any noun doesn't mean it can be used anywhere arbitrarily.

For example this pop-corn label from @Luke's comment doesn't make sense in French:

[image]

At least, it should have read ***Saveur très beurre*** to stay grammatical but even that phrasing is unlikely to have been retained by the marketing department.

Proper translations might be:

> ***Maïs à éclater au bon goût de beurre***

or

> ***Maïs à éclater (goût) extra-beurre***.

Comment: ha, i suppose now the next thing i need to understand is when nouns can be used adjectivally! but that's understanding that i'll just hope i'll get after being exposured to more sentences where nouns are used adjectivally, over the course of the next few years.  but your answer does answer my posted questoin!

Comment: I suspect any noun can be used adjectivally, provided you find a suitable context. e.g. *Ce vélo fait très moto*.

Comment: Can you articulate why **[this](https://i.imgur.com/D4cEvcz.jpg)** is wrong (as it seems to me)?

Comment: @LukeSawczak It is very wrong indeed, even ridiculously funny.

Comment: In English, extra butter is what you ask for at the movies or from a popcorn stand. The choices are: **no butter, butter and extra butter**.  Extra butter flavor means: It *tastes like* it has extra butter. *Au beurre, sans beurre, et??* Je ne sais pas. *Au goût très beurré*?

Comment: @Lambie I don't think *Goût très beurré* would be appealing, *Extra beurre* or maybe *Double beurre* would be fine.

Comment: Le flan de la maison Savary, "à la fois onctueux et très beurré". Ne tirez pas sur le messager.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, on peut en trouver quelques occurrences. C'est la collocation de l'adjectif *beurré* avec *goût* que je ne trouve pas très heureuse et il me semble que *goût beurre* passe beaucoup mieux mais les goûts et les couleurs, ça ne se discute pas. En France, *beurré* est aussi synonyme de *bourré*  (*drunk*) mais ça n'a pas d'importance pour le marché Québecois.

Comment: Je trouverais usuel _à saveur intense de beurre_ au Québec, la pub est vraiment genre perle du mois de la traduction loufoque, même si _très beurre/é_ a peut-être été employé sans aucun lien avec une traduction ailleurs, ce qui donne comme une impression de coller?

Comment: Could be a play on phrase "très belle"?

Comment: @JohnJiang At best a failed attempt: *à saveur de très belle* would be equally wrong.